# WCF service with Windows authentication throws exception "Username not defined" even if it is defined

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I'm consuming a WCF service on a C# Console project. This WCF service uses the Windows authentication and HTTPS so I modified my App.config like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="TestYannisSOAPBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="xxxxx.xxxx.eu" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TestYannisSOAPBinding1" />
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxx.xxxxx.eu/TESTYANNIS_WEB/awws/TestYannis.awws"
              binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestYannisSOAPBinding"
              contract="ServiceReference1.TestYannisSOAPPortType" name="TestYannisSOAPPort" />
    </client>        
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, I specify a security mode `TransportWithMessageCredential`, with transport as a Windows client credential type.

On my code behind, I do specify those Windows credentials like this :

```cs
TestYannisSOAPPortTypeClient client = new TestYannisSOAPPortTypeClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "yannis";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "xxxxxx";
```

At runtime, I receive this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Username not defined. Specify a username in ClientCredentials.

I can get rid of this exception by specifying username and password like this:

```cs
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yannis";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxx";
```

However this time I get an exception from the remote server that doesn't want me to authenticate that way. Why is it digging only in the `client.ClientCredentials` and not in `Windows.ClientCredential`?

I can say that the WCF service works on server side by using a service testing software called Ready!API. Here is a screenshot of the exact same request:

[image]

I guess the problem is on my App.config but I already tried everything. Security mode as `Transport`, with or without the `Message` object etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to this row of your app config:

```
 <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
```

But i'm not understand why do you modify your app config. Usually when you add service reference, it generate right binding based on wsdl of service.
To use windows authentication you should write in your binding something like:

```
  <binding name="TestYannisSOAPBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" ... />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

You can allready try this case:

```
        <binding name="TestYannisSOAPBinding">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: Hey Kirill, i think that you missed your CTRL+V. What row are you talking about ? And unfortunately, just adding service reference doesn't generate the right App.Config in my case... No HTTPS and no Windows auth by default.

Comment: Thank you but what am I supposed to write instead ?
clientCredentialType can have only Certificate or UserName value... Both doesn't work.

Comment: You should not add this row at all. there should be something like this:<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>

Comment: It doesn't work either. First there is only two security modes available : "Transport" and "TransportWithMessageCredential". If I switch to Transport and delete the <message> row as you suggest, i receive an exception of type  System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' which says that My HTTP request is not authorized with a 'Negociate' authentication scheme. Auth header received from server was "Basic realm=xxxxxx"
Error 401 inside the inner exception

Comment: What if you wrote <message clientCredentialType="Windows"> instead of "UserName"?

Comment: Use wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpsBinding. It permits Windows as Client Credential Type http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/wcf-message-level-security-by-example.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You Dont need to specify the transport security tag. Since you are secured using an HTTPS connection hence transport is already secured. There would be no effect of the transport tag in your application for this security mode. For the error you are getting, make sure you only enable anonymous authentication in IIS. Then try running the application again.